# Fill N/A values with existing values in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing some empty values:

```
A      B      C
1      Red    3 
2      Blue   4
3      Green  5
1      Red    ? 
2      Blue   ?
3      Green  ?
```

I want to fill the "?" with the corresponding values (The first ? 3, the second ? 4 and the third ? 5)

Comment: Is there any reason you're using duplicate data from a data set?

Comment: No reason, I only want to know if there is a R Code that can do the fill using the pattern of the columns A and B :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, C :=  C[C!="?"][1L] , by = B][, C := as.numeric(C)]
df1
#   A     B C
#1: 1   Red 3
#2: 2  Blue 4
#3: 3 Green 5
#4: 1   Red 3
#5: 2  Blue 4
#6: 3 Green 5
```

---

Or a similar option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(B) %>%
   mutate(C = as.numeric(C[C!= "?"][1L]))
```

NOTE: We assume the 'B' column as `character` class

Comment: What means the [1L]? Is necessary?

Comment: @CharlyCastro  It is selecting the first observation.  You can also use `[1]`, but I prefer the integer version (`L`) as it could be more efficient